# How to query if parameter is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'clients'.it has 4 column-'name','address','phone','district'.I want to search based on these 4 information.From these 4 attribute,Some of them may be given and some of them are not.Now,if 2 information are given,how can i search them?And what if 3 information are given?
Can i use a single query that can search based on any number of attribute given?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you draw a simple table and show the result you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate query in php and add where clause if need, something like that:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from clients';
if ($param !== null) {
    $query .= " where name='{$parm}'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton.This way it works.I should think about this way.I was trying using IFNULL()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from clients where (:param IS NULL OR name = :param)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a base sql statement and a where clause that is only added to the final sql qyery if `$parms` is not null.

```
$sql='select * from `clients`';
if( !is_null( $parm ) ) $sql.=' where `name`="'.$parm.'";';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

```
SELECT * from clients where name=IFNULLIF(name,'$parm')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(empty($parm))
{
   SELECT * from clients ;
}
else
{
  SELECT * from clients where name=$parm;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get `$name` variable?